# how can i change this SQL to Django ORM code?

Tags: python, django, orm

```sql
select *
from sample
join process
on sample.processid = process.id
where (processid) in (
    select max(processid) as processid
    from main_sample
    group by serialnumber
) 
ORDER BY sample.create_at desc;
```

models.py

```py
class Sample(models.Model):
    processid = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
    serialnumber = models.CharField(max_length=256)  ##
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

class Process(models.Model):
    sample = models.ForeignKey(Sample, blank=False, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Hi I have two models and I need to change this SQL query to Django ORM, Python code.

I need to **retrieve the latest Sample(by processid) per unique serial number**.

**for example,**

[image]

=> after RUN query

[image]

How can I change the SQL query to ORM code?
how can i change the subquery to ORM?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want as a result and share your models? It looks like you want to retrieve the latest Sample (by processid) per unique serialnumber? Do you need the full result(s) or just some individual values/columns?

Comment: Thanks! I need to retrieve the latest Sample(by processid) per unique serial number!! 
I added the example.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: To also order by a column that is not one of the distinct or retrieved columns you can fall-back on subqueries. To filter by a single row from a subquery you can use the syntax described in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#limiting-the-subquery-to-a-single-row)

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef
subquery = Subquery(Sample.objects.filter(
    serialnumber=OuterRef('serialnumber')
).order_by(
    '-processid'
).values(
    'processid'
)[:1])
results = Sample.objects.filter(
    processid=subquery
).order_by(
    'create_at'
)
```

When using PostgreSQL you can pass fields to [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to get a single result per a certain column, this returns the first result so combined with ordering will do what you need

```
Sample.objects.order_by('serialnumber', '-processid').distinct('serialnumber')
```

If you don't use PostgreSQL. Use a [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values) query of the column that should be unique and then annotate the queryset with the condition that should group the values, `Max` in this case

```
from django.db.models import Max
Sample.objects.order_by(
    'serialnumber'
).values(
    'serialnumber'
).annotate(
    max_processid=Max('processid')
)
```

Comment: Really thanks for replying! I tried your code so I can get the filtered result ! but how can i get the sorted elements by 'create_at' ?? I missed the question for the sorting field.

If I add the order_by('create_at') option after the ORM, it returns **all** the Sample elements, not filtered elements...

Comment: and can I ask that if i can get the other fields (create_date etc)?
this ORM can only get 'serial_number' and max process id.

Comment: @Shale Added an update to the answer at the top, using a subquery what you want should be possible. The update should get you the actual model instances/rows instead of just values which I think is what you want

Comment: Really really really thanks!  you saved my life !!!! @Iain

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

1. If want multiple related objects

```
samples = Sample.objects.prefetch_related('process').group_by('serialinumber')
```

2. If you want related objects for only one object

```
samples = Sample.objects.filter(id=1).select_related('process').group_by('serialinumber')
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! But How can i change the subquery (where (processid) in (
    select max(processid) ...
) ) to ORM? 
I need the MAX processid by each serialnumber

Comment: Need to write another query on first query: say `samples.objects.latest(process__id) ` latest will give the last process__id